# How to use encoding to read dropped unicode texts C#

Tags: c#, character-encoding, drag-and-drop

I'd like to read unicode texts from Chrome-browser by a drop event. My default encoding might be '**EUC-KR**'. The texts could be '**English**, **한국어**, **日本語**, **中國語**, **Русский**'. To do this, I tried following C# codes without any encodings:

**MainWindow XAML Code**

```
AllowDrop="True"
PreviewDrop="Window_PreviewDrop"
```

**Code Behinds**

```
private void Window_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text, true))
    {
        var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text, true);
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (data is string)
            {
                this.Title = data as string; // done!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I dragged texts above and I got these brokens: '**English**, **?쒓뎅??**, **?ζ쑍沃?**, **訝?쐦沃?**, **????克龜橘**'. Some articles said I could use **System.Text.Encoding** to recover the broken words but I failed several times. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try interpreting the dropped text as UTF8 encoded?

Comment: @PepitoSh Yes, but I failed and find another clue from DataFormats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using **DataFormats.UnicodeText** instead **DataFormats.Text**

```
private void Window_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.UnicodeText, true))
    {
        var data = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, true);
        if (data != null)
        {
            if (data is string)
            {
                this.Title = data as string; // done!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thank you for comments!